# kafka Python - CommitFailedError

Tags: python, apache-kafka

**Problem:** when calling `commit()`, I am getting the error if message execution is taking a long time.

Here is the code I am using :

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic,
      group_id='my-group',
      value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf-8')),
      bootstrap_servers=kafka_server_url,
      api_version=(0, 10, 1),
      auto_offset_reset='earliest',
      enable_auto_commit= False,
      #consumer_timeout_ms=3000,
      session_timeout_ms=250000, #The timeout used to detect failures when using Kafka group management facilities. 
      request_timeout_ms=300000,
      heartbeat_interval_ms=80000,
      #max_poll_records=100,#The maximum number of records returned in a single call to poll(). Default: 500
      enable_auto_commit=False,
      retry_backoff_ms = 1000
      )
errored = False
while errored is False:
  logging.warn("Polling new messages from queue ......")
  messages = []
  crs = [] # Store all consumer records
  try:
    tpd = (consumer.poll(max_records=1))
    [crs.extend(tp) for tp in tpd.values()] # List of cr's
    [messages.extend([cr.value]) for cr in crs] 
    if(len(messages)):
      consumer.commit()
      logging.warn("{} messages available in queue".format(len(messages)))
      for msg in messages:
        if(self.__validators.is_valid_message(msg)):
          self.process_message(msg);
        else:
          continue
      # If auto_commit_enable is False, remember to commit() periodically    
      logging.warn("All messages processed. Commiting kafka consumer")

  except Exception as e:
    message = "Error occured while processing message Exception {}".format(e)
    logging.critical(message,exc_info=True)
    errored = True
    break
  logging.info("Sleeping for 5 Seconds")
  time.sleep(3)

def process_message(self,message):
 print("Processed")
```

Following is the error trace:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "message_consumer.py", line
>   413, in consume_messages consumer.commit() File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 472,
>   in commit self._coordinator.commit_offsets_sync(offsets) File
>   "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/coordinator/consumer.py", line
>   398, in commit_offsets_sync raise future.exception # pylint:
>   disable-msg=raising-bad-type kafka.errors.CommitFailedError:
>   CommitFailedError: Commit cannot be completed since the group has
>   already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This
>   means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than
>   the configured session.timeout.ms, which typically implies that the
>   poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can
>   address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing
>   the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

My message is not getting committed and it is getting reprocessed from kafka queue. How do I solve this? Please help.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: you can look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46497352/kafka-replays-messages-over-and-over-heartbeat-session-expired-marking-coord